# Print PHP text from json

Tags: php

There is such a json from the Wikipedia API: https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=Apple

How to output text from php field in php where short text starts?

I tried like this, but nothing works:

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=Apple'); 
$yummy = json_decode($url, true); 
echo $yummy['extract'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this I debug that you exract in **query > page > number**

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=Apple'); 
$yummy = json_decode($url, true); 
$datas=$yummy['query']['pages'];

foreach($datas as $data){
  $extract =  $data['extract'];
}

echo $extract;
```

Comment: Thanks! And if the number 39726 changes, how to automatically withdraw?

Comment: I don't know what is that number but it should be dynamic. So I think from your side you can pass that dynamic number `$yummy['query']['pages'][$number]['extract'];`

Comment: This does not work :( The number is constantly changing

Comment: Your pages array will be multiple?

Answer (score -1):

test is OK

```
  $url = file_get_contents('https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=Apple'); 
$yummy = json_decode($url, true); 
$yummys=$yummy['query']['pages'];
foreach($yummys as $yummy)
  echo $yummy['extract'];
```